# No authenticator available for programmatic login

Tags: authentication, servlets, jboss7.x, resteasy, servlet-container

I keep getting this error whenever I try to login with two different users in two different sessions.

13:27:28,444 ERROR [com.commit.steam.rest.RestLoginService] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Error on login: javax.servlet.ServletException: No authenticator available for programmatic login
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:3254) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1082) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at com.commit.steam.rest.RestLoginService.login(RestLoginService.java:128) [steam-rest-api-0.1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:]

from standalone.xml:

```
<security-domain name="steam" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/STEAMDS"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select U.PASSWORD from USERS U where U.EMAIL=?"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select R.NAME, 'Roles' from USERS U join USER_ROLES UR on U.ID = UR.USER_ID join ROLES R on UR.ROLE_ID = R.ID where U.EMAIL=?"/>
                        <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
                        <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
  <security-domain>steam</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

I use JBoss-as 7.1.1.Final

While debugging I can see that the first request (HttpServletRequest.context.authenticator) has the NonLoginAuthenticator and the login with the second session doesn't have any authenticator attached to it (i.e. HttpServletRequest.context.authenticator is null).
Every following request in the first session has the same Authenticator on the request (when I test business flows for one user).

The HttpServletRequest is injected in the class level

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

protected HttpServletRequest request() {
    return this.request;
}
```

(I tried to move the injection to method level and it didn't help). My rest class is annotated as @Stateless bean (to allow injections).

I tried switching the sessions (I use Chrome and FireFox to ensure different sessions) but it didn't change anything.

Does anyone have any idea or lead on where I need to look for this issue?

Thanks a lot
Avi

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<security-constraint>` element to your web.xml. Something like this:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
              <web-resource-name>Permit all</web-resource-name>
              <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
              <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```